# Completion for filenames without root, only extension (hidden files)

Tags: fish

I'm trying to write a completion for a command that takes filenames that have no root/base part, only extension (such as "foo/.ext"). Hidden files. (Specifically, ".envrc" for [direnv](https://direnv.net).)

There are several examples to follow in fish's installation that use
[__fish_complete_suffix](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/master/share/functions/__fish_complete_suffix.fish) for files that have a root *and* extension, such as [fish](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/master/share/completions/fish.fish) itself:

```
complete -c fish -k -x -a "(__fish_complete_suffix .fish)"
```

The same thing for hidden files, files without a root, doesn't work.

```
# completions/foo.fish
complete -c foo -k -x -a "(__fish_complete_suffix .bar)"

# functions/foo.fish
function foo
    echo $argv
end

> mkdir -p a/b; touch a/1.bar a/2.bar a/.bar
> foo a/<TAB>
a/1.bar  a/2.bar  a/b/
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with this or some other function(s)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fish [doesn't add hidden files to the list of completions unless the token being completed](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/3707#issuecomment-271119234) already starts with a '`.`'.

You should be able to write a custom completion that does what you want, but unfortunately a [long-standing bug](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/3707) makes that impossible.

Comment: Since I was never able to work around that long-standing bug, your answer seems to best answer my question.

Comment: This long-standing bug has now been fixed, as of fish 3.7.0 AFAIK: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/3707

Answer (score 1):

I spent way too much time on this, it may be overly complex, and probably needs to be optimized and simplified, but it does work in almost every case. The one case that doesn't is the outstanding bug @Zanchey mentioned.

```
# completions/foo.fish
complete -c foo -k -x -a "(__fish_complete_dotfile_or_subdirectories .bar)"

function __fish_complete_dotfile_or_subdirectories -d "Complete dotfile or directories"

    set -l token
    set -l suffix
    switch (count $argv)
        case 1
            set token (commandline -ct)
            set suffix $argv
        case 2
            set token $argv[1]
            set suffix $argv[2]
    end

    set -l suffix_len (string length $suffix)

    # trim leading . from suffix if present
    if test (string sub -l 1 $suffix) = "."
        set suffix_len (math $suffix_len - 1)
        set suffix (string sub -l $suffix_len -s "-"$suffix_len $suffix)
    end

    set -l root_name (string split -rm 1 "/" $token)
    set -l root $root_name[1..-2]"/"
    set -l name $root_name[-1]

    # build regex
    # $suffix = foo  ->  '^(?:|\.|\.f|\.fo|\.foo)$'
    # $suffix = bar  ->  '^(?:|\.|\.b|\.ba|\.bar)$'
    set -l re (
        echo -n "^(?:|\."
        for i in (seq $suffix_len)
            echo -n "|\."(string sub -l $i $suffix)
        end
        echo ')$'
    )
    if string match -qr $re "$name"
        set -l i
        if test -n "$root"
            set i (printf "%s.%s" $root $suffix)
        else
            set i (printf ".%s" $suffix)
        end
        if test -f "$i"
            printf "%s\n" $i
        end
    end

    # all subdirs except . and ..
    for i in (complete -C "nonexistentcommand $token" |
        string match -er '[^\.]/$')
        printf "%s\n" $i
    end

end
```

* (`complete -C ...` line [inspiration](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/3.1.2/share/functions/__fish_complete_directories.fish#L18))

```
> mkdir -p a/{.a1,.a2,b1,b2,.b3,.b4} c
> touch .bar .baz a/.bar a/.baz a/foo.bar c/.bar
> tree -aF
.
├── a/
│   ├── .a1/
│   ├── .a2/
│   ├── b1/
│   ├── b2/
│   ├── .b3/
│   ├── .b4/
│   ├── .bar
│   ├── .baz
│   └── foo.bar
├── .bar
├── .baz
└── c/
    └── .bar

> foo <TAB>
> __fish_complete_dotfile_or_subdirectories "" bar
.bar                # .bar is included ...
a/
c/
> foo <TAB>
a/  c/              # ... but is not here because of the long-standing bug
> foo .<TAB>        # completes to `foo .bar`
> foo ./<TAB>
./.bar  ./a/  ./c/  # now it's included
> foo ./.<TAB>      # completes to `foo ./.bar`
> foo a<TAB>        # completes to `foo a/`
> foo a/<TAB>
a/.bar  a/b1/  a/b2/
> foo a/.<TAB>
a/.bar  a/.a1/  a/.a2/  a/.b3/  a/.b4/
> foo a/.b<TAB>
a/.bar  a/.b3/  a/.b4/
> foo a/.ba<TAB>    # completes to `foo a/.bar`
> foo c<TAB>        # completes to `foo c/`
> foo c/<TAB>       # completes to `foo c/.bar`
```

Comment: This long-standing bug has now been fixed, as of fish 3.7.0 AFAIK: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/3707